# PyTorch won't detect gpu's from other nodes in SLURM cluster

Tags: python, pytorch, slurm

I am trying to execute a code in a SLURM cluster where I am requesting 4 nodes with 2 GPUs each. The idea that I want to apply is the following one:

```
models = [MyModel().to(f'cuda{i}') for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count())]

# Use torch multiprocessing to forward some kind of data in each of the models
```

However, even if I ask for 4 nodes and 2 GPUs to SLURM, `torch.cuda.device_count()` will only see the GPUs in the node running the main thread. My question is how could I do to access the other cuda devices in the other nodes so as to run the code in parallel?(nn.DataParallel(model) is not an option as I want to load a different model to each device).

I checked that indeed SLURM is giving me the resources I asked for:

```
import os
import torch

# Some prints that might be useful
print('SLURM_NTASKS =', os.environ['SLURM_NTASKS'])
print('SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE =', os.environ['SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE'])
print('SLURM_GPUS_PER_NODE =', os.environ['SLURM_GPUS_PER_NODE'])
print('SLURM_NNODES =', os.environ['SLURM_NNODES'])
print()
print(torch.cuda.device_count())
```

whose output is:

```
SLURM_NTASKS = 8
SLURM_TASKS_PER_NODE = 2(x4)
SLURM_GPUS_PER_NODE = volta:2
SLURM_NNODES = 4

2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this is not what I exactly want. As I said I want to load a different model in each GPU so DistributedDataParallel is not an option.

Comment: I’m about 99.999% sure that what you envisage isn’t possible. There is nothing automagic in CUDA, SLURM, or standard PyTorch that supports distributed memory systems in the way you seem to be expecting. At best, you might be able to try one of the distributed backends and see if they support what you want: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html

Comment: If you want to run different models on different GPUs than create a new python file for each model and submit as an arrray of jobs.